# How to get the first element of a List of Lists without the extra []?

Tags: haskell

I have a list [[1,2],[3,4]] for example, and `take 1` or `__!!1` just returns [[1,2]].

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but how can I just return [1,2]?

Comment: `head [[1,2],[3,4]]`.

Comment: `[[1,2], [3,4]] !! 1` evaluates to `[1, 2]`, not `[[1, 2]]` (same as `head`, though using `head` is more idiomatic)

Comment: Usually the best way to get at elements of lists is to _pattern match_ on them. This is particularly preferrable because it also forces you to handle cases where the expected elements are not actually present.

Comment: `[[1,2],[3,4]] !! 1` evaluates to `[3,4]`, but that is perhaps a separate issue.

Comment: `mconcat . take 1`